# Azure Bot Services quota limit

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

We would like to automate the creation of BotServices for our customers with ARM template.
When a customer want to create a new bot, we create a new bot channel registration with sepecific settings (Channels, Oauth ...).
We will create this new bot channel registration on our Azure subscription.

Is there any limit to the number of Bot Services instances we can create per subscription ?
There is nothing written in the documentation nor the princing page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a limit to the number of bot channel registrations that can be created. There is both a limit to the number that can be created within a tenant as well as by each non-admin user. The doc, [Azure AD service limits and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions), under Resources, states:

- A maximum of 50,000 Azure AD resources can be created in a single tenant by users of the Free edition of Azure Active Directory by default. If you have at least one verified domain, the default Azure AD service quota for your organization is extended to 300,000 Azure AD resources. Azure AD service quota for organizations created by self-service sign-up remains 50,000 Azure AD resources even after you performed an internal admin takeover and the organization is converted to a managed tenant with at least one verified domain. This service limit is unrelated to the pricing tier limit of 500,000 resources on the Azure AD pricing page. To go beyond the default quota, you must contact Microsoft Support.
- A non-admin user can create no more than 250 Azure AD resources. Both active resources and deleted resources that are available to restore count toward this quota. Only deleted Azure AD resources that were deleted fewer than 30 days ago are available to restore. Deleted Azure AD resources that are no longer available to restore count toward this quota at a value of one-quarter for 30 days. If you have developers who are likely to repeatedly exceed this quota in the course of their regular duties, you can create and assign a custom role with permission to create a limitless number of app registrations.

As creating a bot channel registration also creates an Azure AD resource, then these limits would apply.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks, I thought they were some limit but i didn't know it was linked to Azure AD apps.